# Ansible: Abort Execution if a host is unreachable

Tags: ansible

Summary: A better way for aborting ansible playbook immediately if any host is unreachable.

Is there a way to abort Ansible playbook if any one of the host is unreachable. What I find that if it cannot reach a host it will still continue on and execute all the plays/tasks in the playbook.

All my playbooks I specify the max_fail_percentage of 0, but in this case ansible does not complain since all the hosts that are reachable can execute all the plays.

Currently I have a simple but hacky solution, but seeing if there is a better answer.

### My current solution:

Since the first step as part of running the playbooks, ansible gathers facts for all the hosts. And in case where a host is not reachable it will not be able to. I write a simple play at the very beginning of my playbook which will use a fact. And in case a host is unreachable that task will fail with "Undefined variable error". The task is just a dummy and will always pass if all hosts are reachable.

See below my example:

```
- name: Check Ansible connectivity to all hosts
  hosts: host_all
  user: "{{ remote_user }}"
  sudo: "{{ sudo_required }}"
  sudo_user: root
  connection: ssh # or paramiko
  max_fail_percentage: 0
  tasks:
    - name: check connectivity to hosts (Dummy task)
      shell: echo " {{ hostvars[item]['ansible_hostname'] }}"
      with_items: groups['host_all']
      register: cmd_output

    - name: debug ...
      debug: var=cmd_output
```

In case a host is unreachable you will get an error as below:

```
TASK: [c.. ***************************************************** 
fatal: [172.22.191.160] => One or more undefined variables: 'dict object'    has no attribute 'ansible_hostname' 
fatal: [172.22.191.162] => One or more undefined variables: 'dict object' has no attribute 'ansible_hostname'

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

Comment: which version of ansible did you use ? cannot make `with_items: groups['host_all']` to work with ansible-playbook 2.7.8 :-/

Answer (score 3):

alternatively, this looks simplier and more expressive

```
- hosts: myservers
  become: true

  pre_tasks:
    - name: Check ALL hosts are reacheable before doing the release
      assert:
        that:
          - ansible_play_hosts == groups.myservers
        fail_msg: 1 or more host is UNREACHABLE
        success_msg: ALL hosts are REACHABLE, go on
      run_once: yes

  roles:
    - deploy
```

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/18782#issuecomment-319409529

Comment: one shortcoming of the above is when using `--limit <one-host>` ... :-/

Answer (score 2):

You can combine `any_errors_fatal: true` ***or*** `max_fail_percentage: 0` with `gather_facts: false`, and then run a task that will fail if the host is offline. Something like this at the top of the playbook should do what you need:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  max_fail_percentage: 0
  tasks:
    - action: ping
```

A bonus is that this also works with the `-l SUBSET` option for limiting matching hosts.

Comment: But what if you need facts?

Comment: Start a new `hosts` block below the one I showed, and do not include the `gather_facts: false` line. You can also use an `- action: setup` task in a playbook/role to trigger fact-gathering.

Comment: This did not work on ansible 2.9.6

Answer (score 1):

You could be a bit more explicit about the check:

```
- fail: Abort if hosts are unreachable
  when: "'ansible_hostname' not in hostvars[item]"
  with_items: groups['all']
```

I thought you could make a [callback plugin](http://docs.ansible.com/developing_plugins.html#callbacks) to achieve this. Something like:

```
class CallbackModule(object):
    def runner_on_unreachable(self, host, res):
        raise Exception("Aborting due to unreachable host " + host)
```

Except I can't find any good way to abort the entire playbook from that callback (the exception doesn't work, return value is ignored and while you could probably abuse `self.playbook` to stop things, there's no public API I can see).

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to use a callback to abort the play as soon as the gather_facts has completed.

By setting the _play_hosts to an empty set, there are no hosts to continue with the play.

```
class CallbackModule(object):

    def runner_on_unreachable(self, host, res):
        # Truncate the play_hosts to an empty set to fail quickly
        self.play._play_hosts = []
```

The result is something like:

```
PLAY [test] *******************************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
fatal: [haderp] => SSH Error: ssh: Could not resolve hostname haderp: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
It is sometimes useful to re-run the command using -vvvv, which prints SSH debug output to help diagnose the issue.
ok: [derp]

TASK: [set a fact] ************************************************************
FATAL: no hosts matched or all hosts have already failed -- aborting


PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
       to retry, use: --limit @/Users/jkeating/foo.yaml.retry

derp                       : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
haderp                     : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from other answers.

Using ansible-playbook 2.7.8.

Checking if there are any `ansible_facts` for each required hosts feels more explicit to me.

```
# my-playbook.yml
- hosts: myservers
  tasks:
    - name: Check ALL hosts are reacheable before doing the release
      fail:
        msg: >
          [REQUIRED] ALL hosts to be reachable, so flagging {{ inventory_hostname }} as failed,
          because host {{ item }} has no facts, meaning it is UNREACHABLE.
      when: "hostvars[item].ansible_facts|list|length == 0"
      with_items: "{{ groups.myservers }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "Will only run if all hosts are reacheable"
```

```
$ ansible-playbook -i my-inventory.yml my-playbook.yml

PLAY [myservers] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [my-host-03]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname my-host-03: Name or service not known", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [my-host-04]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname my-host-04: Name or service not known", "unreachable": true}
ok: [my-host-02]
ok: [my-host-01]

TASK [Check ALL hosts are reacheable before doing the release] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
failed: [my-host-01] (item=my-host-03) => {"changed": false, "item": "my-host-03", "msg": "[REQUIRED] ALL hosts to be reachable, so flagging my-host-01 as failed, because host my-host-03 has no facts, meaning it is UNREACHABLE."}
failed: [my-host-01] (item=my-host-04) => {"changed": false, "item": "my-host-04", "msg": "[REQUIRED] ALL hosts to be reachable, so flagging my-host-01 as failed, because host my-host-04 has no facts, meaning it is UNREACHABLE."}
failed: [my-host-02] (item=my-host-03) => {"changed": false, "item": "my-host-03", "msg": "[REQUIRED] ALL hosts to be reachable, so flagging my-host-02 as failed, because host my-host-03 has no facts, meaning it is UNREACHABLE."}
failed: [my-host-02] (item=my-host-04) => {"changed": false, "item": "my-host-04", "msg": "[REQUIRED] ALL hosts to be reachable, so flagging my-host-02 as failed, because host my-host-04 has no facts, meaning it is UNREACHABLE."}
skipping: [my-host-01] => (item=my-host-01)
skipping: [my-host-01] => (item=my-host-02)
skipping: [my-host-02] => (item=my-host-01)
skipping: [my-host-02] => (item=my-host-02)
        to retry, use: --limit @./my-playbook.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
my-host-01 : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
my-host-02 : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
my-host-03 : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
my-host-04 : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

Comment: Also one will want to use this in `pre_tasks:`, if you are using `roles:`

Comment: if using ansible-playbook 2.1.1.0, one may want to use `when: "'ansible_system' not in hostvars[item]"` instead

Answer (score 0):

On ansible 2.9.6
with

```
gather_facts: no
```

Following task block worked for me

```
tasks:
  - block:
      - action: ping
    any_errors_fatal: true
```